# How to enforce group-writable permission for whole directory tree?

Tags: linux, permissions

My working group uses a shared directory on a linux server which is made group-writable (and group-executable). Users access this directory both via NFS from Linux boxes and via SMB from windows boxes.

Occasionally, users create a new subdirectory (which is ok) inside this shared folder but this subdirectory is often not group-writable. Is there a way how I (as the superuser) can enforce that all subdirectories created - no matter how - always get the group-writable flag?

What I do at the moment is an occasional recursive chmod g+w, but it would be much better if subdirectories were created with the correct permissions in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, afaik

- umask
- acl

**umask** is the simplest way to go: you'll find a complete explanation [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

"umask 002" says that write permission wont be stripped off group rights for new files or directories

So your problem could be solved by a smart placement of "umask 002" in /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc, if you want to make this the default system wise option, or in individual .profile or .bashrc

**acl** is a more elaborate solution, which allows to specify which users and groups will have what permissions on new files and directories

More info on that [here](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/acl.htm).

Hope that helps :)